# How many passwords of length $6$ can be written using English small letters and digits such that each password has at least $2$ digits?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I hope someone can answer it and explain it to me because I have an exam in 6 hours :)

I went with $26 \cdot 26 \cdot 26 \cdot 26 \cdot 10 \cdot 10$. But it says "at least" $2$ digits, so I'm not sure if I have to go with $36 \cdot 36 \cdot 36 \cdot 36 \cdot 10 \cdot 10$.

Comment: What have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I went with 26*26*26*26*10*10. But it says "at least" 2 digits so I'm not sure if I have to go with 36*36*36*36*10*10.

Comment: I edited the question to include your attempt.  When you post a question here, you should include your own thoughts on the problem.  For an exercise such as this, you should explain what you have attempted and where you are stuck.

Comment: Thank you for the edit and the answer. I'm new to this platform, I will add my attempts to my questions from now on if I have any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are $26$ letters in the English alphabet and $10$ decimal digits, the number of six character passwords that can be formed without restrictions is $36^6$.  From these, we must exclude those with fewer than two digits.

Passwords with no digits:  There are $26^6$ passwords that contain only letters.

Passwords with exactly one digit:  We choose one of the six positions for the digit, choose one of the ten digits to place in that position, and fill the remaining five positions with letters in $6 \cdot 10 \cdot 26^5$ ways.

Hence, the number of permissible passwords is $36^6 - 26^6 - 6 \cdot 10 \cdot 26^5$.